# Django 1.9: CSRF token missing or incorrect using Stripe

Tags: django, csrf, stripe-payments, django-csrf, django-1.9

This might be a duplicate but i tried using `RequestContext` from other answers but it didnt work for me

**checkout_test.html**:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_37uDrOYvvyyJSLoV0ziJcYyl"
        data-amount="2000"
        data-name="Demo Site"
        data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
        data-image="/128x128.png"
        data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def user_review_list(request, username=None, errmsg=None):
    return render(request, 'checkout_test.html', {})
```

so in `user_review_list.html`, there is a button provided by stripe
when i fill out info and click the button, it raises error:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

How can i fix this?

I've already tried changing `render` to `render_to_response` with `RequestContext` but that didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass your CSRF cookie to Stripe and back. One workaround is to use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def user_review_list(request, username=None, errmsg=None):
    ...
```